# Where should _declspec be placed?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dllexport

I'm in the process of switching from a def file to using _declspec for a library I maintain. I have read several of the questions here on SO and the MSDN documentation. I understand how the feature works. I have created macros and use `_declspec` or gcc `__attribute__` depending on the build environment. The macros also properly select between `_declspec(dllexport)` and `_declspec(dllimport)`.

Is there any harm in using `_declspec` on the function definitions? Should `_declspec` only be used on the function prototypes?

I would prefer to have the marco on both the function prototype and definition. I did test using `_declspec` on both the function prototype and definition. Using VS the library compiled without warnings and I was able to use the library without issue.

Answer (score 0):

NO harm on function defination - sing __declspec(dllimport) is optional on function declarations, but the compiler produces more efficient code if you use this keyword. However, you must use __declspec(dllimport) for the importing executable to access the DLL's public data symbols and objects.
It is mostly used for importing symbols from / exporting symbols to a shared library (DLL). Both Visual C++ and GCC compilers support __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport).

You can also use it for variables.